# Creating a directed graph with multiple sources and destinations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I'm Trying to create a directed graph that points from one source to a destination which in turn points to a new destination. How can I add the second source to destination onto my graph?

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/FAFData.csv', usecols = ['FR_ORIG','DMS_ORIG','DMS_DEST','TotalM'])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2,source = 'FR_ORIG',target = 'DMS_ORIG', edge_attr='TotalM',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw(G,pos,node_size=60,with_labels = True,font_size=16,font_color='blue' ,reverse=True)
```

My current results look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsgki.jpg

I'm trying to get it to look like how I've sketched on the image.

Edited for clarity:

I have a table with 4 columns, FR_ORIG, DMS_ORIG DMS_DEST and TotalM.
I'm trying to create a directed graph where the FR_ORIG points to DMS_ORIG which in turn points to DMS_DEST. So Far I've managed to create the graph where FR_ORIG points to DMS_ORIG but I do not know how to include DMS_DEST in the graph.

Here is a picture of the table that I have as well as a sketch of what I am trying to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktl9h.jpg

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want it to look like.  Can you give more explanation?

Comment: added clarification